# How to activate Mathematica through remote license server from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, licensing

I am trying to activate Mathematica from the command line (I am logged remotely) by connecting to a remote network license server, but no success so far. I run the command `math` but Mathematica keeps asking me for the activation key and password. Is it possible to choose the network license server as the way to activate Mathematica from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to just edit the `mathpass` file to contain a line that has `!server`, where `server` is the name of your network license server.

[tutorial/ConfigurationFiles](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html) should help you determine where the `mathpass` file is for your platform.  (If it doesn't exist, just create it.)

Comment: I created the mathpass file in `/usr/share/Mathematica/Licensing/` and put the line as you advised. It worked! Thanks!